# Better to use NSString or NSMutableString in loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

For the task of converting an array of strings to a single comma-delimited string, I'm wondering if there's a significant advantage to either the NSString approach or the NSMutableString approach below. (In both cases, allNames is an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`.)

NSString approach

```
NSString *listOfNames=[allNames objectAtIndex:0];
for (int i=1;i<[allNames count];i++){
   NSString *thisName=[allNames objectAtIndex:i];
   listOfNames=[listOfNames stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@",thisName];
}
```

NSMutableString approach

```
NSMutableString *mutableListOfNames=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[mutableListOfNames appendString:allNames[0]];
for (int i=1;i<[allNames count];i++){
    NSString *thisName=[allNames objectAtIndex:i];
    [mutableListOfNames appendFormat:@", %@",thisName];
}
NSString *listOfNames=[NSString stringWithString:mutableListOfNames];
```

Comment: The difference is that the `NSString` approach creates and deallocs a lot of objects in a short space of time. Whereas `NSMutableString` avoids this. As your programs are managed by ARC this may not make a huge difference in the long run.

Comment: Is it OK that your string result looks like this: `@", foo, bar"` ?

Comment: All of your code can be replaced with one line: `NSString *listOfNames = [allNames componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

Comment: @ThomasW: I thought I'd avoided that by picking out the first list item before the loop? Seems to work as expected when I run it.

Comment: @rmaddy: Thanks for the shortcut, that will be helpful! A big part of the question for me was trying to better understand the practical nature of NSString and NSMutableString, but yes, I'm sure I'll put your code to good use in future!

Comment: @Rogare With the `NSMutableString` approach that you have above the code will fail unless the first NSString in allNames is an `NSMutableString`. This will also discard the originally allocated `NSMutableString`.

Comment: @ThomasW Good catch. That's easily fixed by changing the 2nd line to `[mutableListOfNames appendString:allNames[0]];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `NSMutableString` is better to use in this case. It avoids the problem of creating a large number of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is something I've wondered about: with the constantly "overlapped" thisName in the NSString approach, is each subsequent value of thisName actually being stored (instead of discarded after each iteration of the loop)?

Comment: Also, it avoids having to release them as well, though under ARC this may not be as big of a concern.

Comment: Debatable (but also measurable.) Although the implementation of `NSMutableString` is effectively opaque, it's not magic -- if the string is growing, allocations *will* be happening. Whether or not those allocations are "smarter" (i.e. fewer) than would happen if you were creating and discarding a bunch of immutable `NSString`s would be something you would have to measure empirically to be sure. The difference is unlikely to matter in practice, unless you're doing a lot of heavy/large string manipulation.

Comment: Also, for the record, ARC doesn't prevent objects from being released, it merely does it automatically. Any performance penalty incurred by retaining and releasing objects is the same whether you're doing it explicitly (MRR) or automatically (ARC).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @ipmcc. So, at the end of each iteration, there won't be accumulating objects then in the NSString approach?

Comment: Yes. In the NSString approach, with ARC, I would expect the previous object stored in `listOfNames` to be released at the end of each pass of the loop. I haven't explicitly tested it, but that would be my expectation based on what I know about ARC (a fair bit).

Comment: @ipmcc The advantage of using ARC is that the objects get released as the loop is running while with MRR they don't get released until the autorelease pool is drained.

Comment: My point was simply that anything ARC can do can be done exactly the same with MRR, and the performance will be exactly the same. There is no free lunch. A quick empirical investigation with Instruments shows that my initial assessment was wrong; you actually need to put the body of the `for` loop in an `@autoreleasepool {}` for it to behave the way I expected. Otherwise those interim objects *do* hang around (i.e. major heap growth for large values of n).